Liveness probe fails for MinIO pod with tls enabled
I am new to kubernetes and trying to setup MinIO on minikube, i am using bitnami MinIO helm-chart. The problem is that the container starts up fine, initiall I am even able to connect to it and list my buckets, however the logs show continuous restarts and the following message: Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.244.0.6:9000/minio/health/live": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client. This error started occuring after i enabled tls, also i have confirmed that the livenesProbe.httpGet.scheme is set as HTTPS.
helmfile.yaml
  - name: minio-release
    namespace: minio
    createNamespace: true
    chart: bitnami/minio
    version: 14.10.3
    values:
      - /values.yaml
    installed: true 
    set:
      - name: auth.rootUser
        value: "root-user"
      - name: auth.rootPassword
        value: "root-password"

values.yaml
mode: distributed
statefulset:
  replicaCount: 4
service:
  type: LoadBalancer

tls:
  enabled: true
  autoGenerated: true

